# CakePHP save associated model data in afterSave

Tags: cakephp

I have a Task model and  project model, tasks belongTo a project, what i wish to do is on the afterSave in the task model, update a field in the project model, but im having trouble i've tried using $this->Task->Project->Find(), with no joy. thanks.

Comment: If you are in Task model, it corresponds to `$this`, so to get the Project model you just do `$this->Project->saveField()` or whatever method you need from the project model

Comment: thanks this actuall clear things up! quite new to MCV frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `saveAll()`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array

Side note:  why would you expect 'find()' to save your data?

Comment: because when i debug the $this->data functionality inside the afterSave function its only returning the Task data, so i was using the project_id field within the task data to find the project, which i know is bad practice.